# Flutter application is not getting updated?

Tags: android, flutter, updates

I have built a flutter app and launched it on playstore.

When the app is installed, and I try to install an apk, when it's already installed, it shows me a message to update the currently installed applications.

However then it gives me a message app not installed.

How do I know what's wrong, I'm out of ways to figure it out.

Comment: which apk? released app apk or debug apk.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget to increase the versionCode in gradle